# How to avoid re render the screen when we come back using functional component

Tags: react-native, rendering

i am new to react native, i am doing application with two screens with functional components. First when i enter the screen A, api called and screen rendered. And next i went to Screen B from Screen A, and render the screen B.Now when i come back from screen B to Screen A, again api called and screen re-rendered. I don't want to re render when i visit the screen again, i want to render only when i first visit that screen until unless i relaunch the app.So please let me know how to avoid this re render.

Answer (score 0):

You can use *react-navigation/stack* to moving between screens.
https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigating

To navigate B, you can call:

```
navigation.navigate('ScreenB')
```

And to go back to A, you can use

```
navigation.goBack()
```

Answer (score 0):

Have wrapped up the API call block inside a useEffect() hook?

If not wrap it up in a useEffect and specify the required dependencies to avoid unnecessary re-calls.